# LINQ select statement gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have made a simple view in SQL and I need this transferred to C#. Firstly, I made a LINQ to SQL class. From the SQL Server Object Explorer, I drag-and-dropped the view into the `.dbml` designer. Then calling the select statement, like so:

```
var list = from test in testDB.v_TestView select test;
```

When running this command, I get the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I'm not quite sure why this simple select statement is bothering me?

Here's the view I made:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_TestView]
    AS select * from TestTable
```

Comment: Did you happen to notice if `testDB` is null? Where is `testDB` instantiated?

Comment: if `v_TestView` is in the .dbml file, then you just call the view.
`var list = from test in v_TestView select test;`